# Where is $KERNEL_VERSION defined

Tags: linux

I was going through some makefiles and I observed that this statement is used quite often

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
```

to see if the file is invoked from the kernel build system . I have tried going into /usr/src/mykernelheaders and tried a printenv. But I still do not see $KERNELRELEASE defined. Where exactly is it defined in linux?

Comment: check in include/config/kernel.release file.

Comment: It says 3.2.29, but how will $KERNELRELEASE decide to check in that particular and not return empty?

Comment: refer http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-4